# How do I specify a custom lookup field for a DRF action on a viewset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I would like to specify a custom lookup field on the action (different from the viewset default "pk"), i.e.

```
@action(
        methods=["GET"],
        detail=True,
        url_name="something",
        url_path="something",
        lookup_field="uuid",  # this does not work unfortunately
    )
    def get_something(self, request, uuid=None):
         pass
```

But the router does not generate the correct urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"test", TestViewSet)
router.urls
```

yields url:

```
'^test/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/something/$'
```

instead of

```
'^test/(?P<uuid>[^/.]+)/something/$'
```

I do not want to change the lookup field for the whole viewset though and have been unsuccessful in finding a way to do this for the action itself after debugging through the router url generation. I did notice that model viewsets have this method:

```
get_extra_action_url_map(self)
```

but am unsure how to get it to be called to generate custom urls or if it is even relevant. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will create much confusion for your API consumers if you have 2 different resource identification on the same resource.

You can name that action `query_by_uuid` or just allow them to use `list_view` to filter by `uuid` if you only want to represent the object tho. (so consumers can use /test/?uuid= to retrieve data)

But if you really want to do it, you can simply override `get_object` method to filter for your custom action tho:

```
def get_object(self):
    if self.action == 'do_something':
        return get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), uuid=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return super().get_object()
```

Here is a bit hacky solution for generate uuid in router with detail=False.

```
@action(detail=False, url_path=r'(?P<uuid>[^/.]+)/do_something')
def do_something(self, request, uuid=None):
    pass
```

Comment: Yes ideally I would not have two lookup fields. For the purpose of this problem however, your suggestion is what I am currently doing to bypass the malformed url issue (i.e. putting a uuid in the pk field for lookups). Ideally the url would show that a uuid is expected though.

Comment: @Rob check the updated answer if it's suitable for you

Comment: That works. It's a hacky problem so a hacky solution makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to their [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) you could use a regex lookup field. Their example uses a CBV instead of a request based view.

```
class MyModelViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    lookup_value_regex = '[0-9a-f]{32}'
```

This could work:

```
@action(
        methods=["GET"],
        detail=True,
        url_name="something",
        url_path="something",
        lookup_field = 'uuid'
        lookup_value_regex = '[0-9a-f]{32}'
    )
    def get_something(self, request, uuid=None):
         pass
```

Comment: If I specify the uuid as the lookup field on the viewset as you have done above it works. However, I was trying to only specify it on the action (which doesn't work). Here I don't care about the lookup value formatting but rather the lookup field itself (being pk by default or uuid). Thanks for the suggestion though!